# How to check if the generic return type of a method matches the class passed via parameter?

Tags: java

I have a `Map` which stores instances of a super class called `DAO`. The user can put different sub-classes of this `DAO` class into the map. The keys of the map are the `Class` of the corresponding model (i.e. `Apple.class`), which are also stored as instance variable in the `DAO` object. The `DAO` instances can then later be retrieved via a getter which uses generics and casts the `DAO` to the desired sub-type.

```java
Map<Class<? extends Model>, DAO> daoMap = new HashMap<>();


// Create and store DAOs
SearchDAO<Apple> appleDAO = new SearchDAO<>(Apple.class);
daoMap.put(Apple.class, appleDAO);
CrudDAO<Orange> orangeDAO = new CrudDAO<>(Orange.class);
daoMap.put(Orange.class, orangeDAO);


// Method to retrieve DAOs
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends DAO> T getDAO(Class<? extends Model> modelClass) {
    return (T) daoMap.get(modelClass);
}
```

To retrieve a DAO you just have to do this:

```java
final SearchDAO<Apple> appleDAO = this.getDAO(Apple.class);
```

This works fine, but now I want a check which throws an exception when the model class in the stored DAO is not equal to `T`. I.e. the following should throw an exception when executed:

```java
final SearchDAO<Orange> orangeDAO = this.getDAO(Apple.class);
```

As said, the `Class` type is also stored in the `DAO` itself. So I would like to have a check like this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends DAO> T getDAO(Class<? extends Model> modelClass) {
    T dao = (T) daoMap.get(modelClass);
    if(!dao.getModelClass() instancof T) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Apples are not Oranges!");
    }
    return dao;
}
```

Would that somehow be possible? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works fine, but now I want a check which throws an exception when
>   the model class in the stored DAO is not equal to T. I.e. the
>   following should throw an exception when executed:

`T` is something that extends `DAO` so the model class is never equal to `T`, as model class is something that extends `Model`.

If you want to make sure that the `DAO` which is stored in the map under a model class key e.g. `Apple.class` has the same `modelClass` instance stored,  you could do it like this:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public <T extends DAO> T getDAO(Class<? extends Model> modelClass) {
    T dao = (T) daoMap.get(modelClass);
    if(!dao.getModelClass().isAssignableFrom(modelClass)) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Apples are not Oranges!");
    }
    return dao;
 }
```

if you now put a `DAO` instance with the model class `Apple.class` in the map under the `Orange.class` key:

```
SearchDAO<Apple> appleDAO = new SearchDAO<>(Apple.class);
daoMap.put(Apple.class, appleDAO);
daoMap.put(Orange.class, appleDAO);
```

and you call for oranges:

```
final SearchDAO<Orange> orangeDAO = getDAO(Orange.class);
```

you get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apples are not Oranges!
```

if this is what you want, you could also think about performing the check when putting `DAO` instances in the map and throwing an exception if the key class is not the same as the modelClass of the `DAO`.